# how do i tell if my prefab fireplace is rated for wood?

Tags: fireplace

i live in a condo building with 9 units. for all intents and purposes they're townhomes (i.e. each one is two stories tall with a fireplace on the first floor and a flue at the roof). the building itself is a converted factory, that was gut/rehabbed in the late 80s.

my fireplace has a gas log in it. it also has a fully functional flue. my neighbors have identical looking fireplaces that are wood burning (that is to say they don't have a readily apparent gas line, and they burn wood in them).

is there any way to tell whether my firebox is rated differently? did a previous owner just prefer the gas log and go that way, or are my neighbors flaunting fire risk and unsafely converting under-rated fireboxes (or their predecessors, rather)?

Comment: Call a local chimney sweep and have the firebox and chimney inspected.  You will get much more accurate info than "guesses" on the internet.

Comment: Clearly that's a requisite validation step. Not my question though.

Comment: If you can't find a make/model/serial number then yourself or  no one here can do anything but guess.

Comment: @JimStewart there are plenty of possible reasons - for example access to free/cheap wood, expensive gas, nostalgia. They're not really material to the question.

Comment: @Chris H, yes I shouldn't have made the comment. However, one does wonder about the decision to add to air pollution by changing to wood. I live in a neighborhood of 45-year-old tract homes, each with an enormous pile of bricks in the form of an over-sized chimney designed to burn wood. Most people in the neighborhood seemingly have changed to gas logs, but some people are still burning wood. When they do the odor is strong.

Comment: I remember years ago on This Old House the project was a barn conversion in MA. The original plan was no external chimney to, one, keep with the original form of a barn, and, two, to not interrupt the carefully engineered insulation envelope. IIRC the homeowner initially went along with this, but then decided to have a traditional brick chimney because he said he had been told that in this area one could not sell a house without it. Norm Abram and the HVAC sub were exasperated, but complied.

Comment: One way to guess and not the best choice without more information. If the bottom of the burn box is metal it is probably gas only. If the bottom has a layer of fire clay or cement looking material it may be for wood burning.